# Upgrading DBGhost from 5.0.0.1108 to 5.0.0.1368

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbghost

Static data are not generating in Delta when I upgraded DBGhost from 5.0.0.1108 to 5.0.0.1368. Is there any workaround for this?, am I doing something wrong?.

Answer (score 1):

This was also posted on our forum where you can see the response. "use the GUI to prepare and save the settings then you can use the settings file for the command line runs."

http://dbghost.forumco.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=225

Jon @ Innovartis